# QTableWidget scroll to a previous value

Tags: qt, scroll, qtablewidget

i've a QTableWidget. 
In this QTableWidget i've loaded 500 rows (7 columns).
The user can scroll the rows through the vertical scrollbar.
I want to save the vertical scrollbar value and apply it automatically at the next startup.
What I did :
On close event i save the vertical scrollbar value :

```
saveToFile(myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->value());
```

on close event, in order to debug i added this lines :

```
qDebug() << "Scroll Min " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->minimum();
qDebug() << "Scroll Max " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();
qDebug() << "Scroll Val " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->value();
```

The output is :

```
Scroll Min  0
Scroll Max  58811
Scroll Val  34758
```

On startUp I read the value from file :

```
int scrollValue = loadFromFile(myFileName);
```

now in the variable scrollValue i've the value 34758.

Then I load the 500 elements in the QTableWidget and run this code :

```
myQTableWidget->setRowCount(500);

for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
   myQTableWidget->setItem(i, 0, ...);
}

//EDIT 15-11-2019
myQTableWidget->resizeRowsToContents(); // <- The guilty row

qDebug() << "Scroll Min " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->minimum();
qDebug() << "Scroll Max " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();

if (scrollValue > 0)
    myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(scrollValue);
```

The strange thing is that the output is different from the previous (the row number doesn't change) :

```
Scroll Min  0
Scroll Max  14906
```

1) Why the Scroll Max is different even if the QTableWidget contains exactly the same items ?
2) Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: It is very suspicious the scroll max values so different. The answer is probably hidden in some place of your code, that you don't show. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution :

```
myQTableWidget->setRowCount(500);

for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
   myQTableWidget->setItem(i, 0, ...);
}

myQTableWidget->resizeRowsToContents(); // <- The guilty row

myQTableWidget->verticalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();

qDebug() << "Scroll Min " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->minimum();
qDebug() << "Scroll Max " << myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();

if (scrollValue > 0)
    myQTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(scrollValue)
```

I added this two lines after the resizeRowsToContents() :

```
myQTableWidget->verticalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

Now the scroll value is correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with the QTableWidget. The values of the scrollbar were not updated.

Try: `myQTableWidget->update();` after inserting new items. The values of the scrollbar should fit now.